# find vs find_first_of when searching for empty string

Tags: c++, string, stl

In STL, when I do `s.find("")`, it returns 0 while `s.find_first_of("")` returns -1 (npos). What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: I'd expect `s.find("");` to return 0 (and it does so with the implementations I have handy). For example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d5a6076bde75e28

Comment: true. thanks for pointing that out. made the change to the question. still does not explain the difference

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`s.find(t)` finds the first occurrence of the substring `t` in `s`. If `t` is empty, then that occurrence is at the beginning of `s`, and `s.find(t)` will return 0.

`s.find_first_of(t)` finds the first occurrence of *one of the characters* in `t`. If `t` is the empty string, then there are no characters in `t`, so no occurrence can be found, and `find_first_of` will return `npos`.

[Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/Rd7box).

Comment: but the beginning of the string does not have "". it has "a" right ?, as in your example. should s.find("') return -1 as well ?

Comment: @littlecegian: "" consists of zero characters and there is certainly a substring of length 0 at the beginning of any string. (There is also a substring of length 0 starting at every other position in the string, if there are other positions, but the one at position 0 is the leftmost one.)

Comment: if that is the case find_first_of should also return 0 since, of all the characters in "", empty string is a character which when searched for returns 0. right ?

Comment: @littlecegian: As I said in the answer, there are no characters in the empty string, so it is not the case that any character in the string is found in the target.