# Which is better to check if a character exists in a std::string? find or find_first_of?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, performance, stl

`std::string` has two different member functions that do the same thing:

```
size_type find( CharT ch, size_type pos = 0 ) const noexcept;
size_type find_first_of( CharT ch, size_type pos = 0 ) const noexcept;
```

If I want to check if a character exists in a `std::string`, which one is preferred in terms of performance?

Comment: I recommend simply to profile both related to your performance measurement.

Comment: Aren't these functions "little different"?

Comment: It looks like MSVC++2015 implements find_first_of(CharT ch, size_type pos = 0) simply by calling find(ch, pos), so they should be the same there.

Comment: @VTT Yes, but the question focuses only on the those two signatures. The answer was provided by LRiO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter. They do the same thing.

Like, literally. [libstdc++ just delegates `find_first_of(char, size_t)` to `find(char, size_t)`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L2567), [as does libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/string#L3489), and MSVS 2015 too (thanks roalz). There's no reason for any implementation to do otherwise.

I'm not really clear on why that overload of `find_first_of` even exists; it could just be for symmetry with `find` (which does something different when you use the other overloads) but to be honest that just seems confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty much identical. But not doing the exact same thing in some specific case and that is depends what std library you are using.

I am using a thing called EWL, (highly likely no 1 is using this anymore) in that library `string::find()` and `string::find_first_of` are the same.

But different libraries have different stories. In some library, e.g Gnu, C++2a, if you searching an empty string from an empty string, `std::find()` returns position 0. However `std::find_first_of()` returns `std::string::npos`. They are right or wrong depends on the different views you have.

The issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424323/find-vs-find-first-of-when-searching-for-empty-string).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. This question is specifically asking about the versions of find and find_first_of which take a character as the first parameter. These always behave identically, and this does not depend on which library you are using. The versions that take strings as the first parameter likewise must always behave as they do (e.g. find("") returns position 0, and find_first_of("") returns string::npos), regardless of what std library you are using. The question you referenced explains why this happens. It has nothing to do with library versions.